# How to refactor this code ?how can i make this code better?

Tags: reactjs, refactoring

I want to learn refactoring but i don't know how can i make my code perfect.

```
class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isClicked: false
  };

  handleClicked = () => {
    const btn = document.querySelector('button');
    const content = document.querySelector('#content');
    if(!this.state.isClicked){
      this.setState({ isClicked: true});
      content.style.display = 'none';
      btn.textContent ='Show';
    } 
    else {
      this.setState({ isClicked: false });
      content.style.display = '';
      btn.textContent ='Hide';
    }
  }

  render() {
    const heading3 = 'this is a heading inside class component';
    const p1 = 'this is a paragraph inside class component';
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClicked}>Hide</button>
        <div id='content'>
          <h1>{heading3}</h1>
          <p>{p1}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ClassComponent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid reading and manipulating the DOM, leave it to React.

For what you need, conditional rendering is just fine.

At first, let's refactor the `handleClick` method: if you think of it, it should just toggle the state `isClicked`. Do this then:

```
handleClicked = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    isClicked: !prevState.isClicked
  }))
}
```

**What's happening here?**

You are doing a `setState`, but you need to access the previous/current state. Due to state updates batching done by React, is safer to pass to the `setState` an updater function, rather than a new object.

The updater function takes a state object as input, and return a new one. The input state object will be provided by React in the `setState` call.

---

Then...

Being able to toggle the `isClicked` prop, you can use the conditional rendering to choose what to render based on this prop value:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleClicked}>
        { this.state.isClicked ? "Hide" : "Show" }
      </button>
      { this.state.isClicked && (
        <div id='content'>
          <h1>this is a heading inside class component</h1>
          <p>this is a paragraph inside class component</p>
        </div>
      }
      </div>
  );
}
```

**What's happening here?**

Here we have two examples of conditional rendering.

The first one is:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClicked}>
  { this.state.isClicked ? "Hide" : "Show" }
</button>
```

Here we are saying: check the `isClicked` property of the state object and, if it's `true`, render the string "Hide", otherwise render the string "Show".

The second conditional rendering technique is:

```
{ this.state.isClicked && (
  <div id='content'>
    <h1>this is a heading inside class component</h1>
    <p>this is a paragraph inside class component</p>
  </div>
}
```

This is a rather common Javascript statement: if the first condition is `true`, then return the other side of the `&&` operator, otherwise just `false`.

React doesn't render `false`, `null`, `undefined` and probably something I am forgotting right now.

This means that, if the `isClicked` property is true, that expression will return the jsx containing the `<div id='content'...` etc that will then be rendered, otherwise `false`, and nothing gets rendered.

Hope it helps.